# Вектор в динамическом массиве

Tags: c, циклы, динамические-массивы, вектор

Дано задание: **Для квадратной матрицы размера n*n подсчитать среднее арифметическое элементов каждого столбца, исключая элемент на главной диагонали, и сформировать из них вектор. Найти минимальный элемент этого вектора.** (Размерность массивов вводит пользователь, значения генерируются. Массив динамический).

```
// Размер массива вводит пользователь (значения случайны)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned n;
    printf("\tСоздание матрицы размером n*n. Введите значение n: ");
    scanf("%u", &n);

    int **arr;
    arr = (int*)malloc(n*n * sizeof(int));

    printf("\n\tМатрица:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] =  rand()%100;
            printf("\t%d ", *(arr + i*n +j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(arr);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Массив создается нормально, но значения через рандом получаются слишком огромными

```
 double k, m, a = 0, vec[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) // среднее арифметическое по столбцам
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(i != j) // исключая элемент на главной диагонали
            a += arr[i][j]; // сумма элементов столбца
        }
        m = a / n; // среднее арифметическое столбца
        vec[j] = m;
        a = 0;
    }

    printf("\n\tВектор:");
    k = vec[0];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("\t%.2f ", vec[j]);
        if (k > vec[j]) // поиск минимального элемента вектора
        k = vec[j];
    }

    printf("\n\tМинимальный элемент вектора = ");
    printf("%.2f", k);
```

Сам вектор не выводится, не очень понимаю как реализовать создание вектора динамического массива. Полагаю, что нужно по другому сделать цикл. Не могу разобраться. Помогите.

Comment: Вектор вообще не выводится в консоль?

Comment: Нет, не выводится

Comment: Хмм... условие внутри цикла на каждое значение столбца — это неэффективно. Попробуйте складывать все, а потом вычитать, после завершения цикла, значение диагонального элемента.

Comment: Дальше, независимо от способа (вашего или моего из предыдущего комментария) вам надо добавить проверок на переполнение. Представьте, если все элементы матрицы со значениями близкими к INT_MAX.

Comment: Коллекционирование суммы целых в типе double — это ошибка. Так делать нельзя.

Comment: Я почитал комментарии, с проблемой разобрался. Всем спасибо !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int **arr;
arr = (int*)malloc(n*n * sizeof(int));
```

`malloc` - возвращает указатель на вектор, а вы этот указатель переделываете на вектор векторов. Происходит несоотвествие типов.

Дальше :

```
arr[i][j] =  rand()%100;
```

здесь вы присваиваете как будто arr - это вектор векторов или матрица, а это не так.

Первый правильный вариант такой, что `arr` - это вектор в памяти:

```
int * arr = malloc(n*n * sizeof(int));
printf("\n\tМатрица:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        *(arr + i*n +j) = rand()%100;
        printf("\t%d ", *(arr + i*n +j));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
free(arr);
```

Второй вариант, выделить память для матрицы :

```
int (* mat)[n][n] = malloc( sizeof(int[n][n]));
printf("\n\tМатрица:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        (*mat)[i][j] =  rand()%100;
        printf("\t%d ", (*mat)[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
free(mat);
```

Вот вам два варианта, ответ на почему средние значения огромные. Потому, что значения брались со случайных мест памяти и происходил конфликт неправильного доступа к памяти.

Ошибка вторая : среднее значение вычисляется **без** диагональных чисел, так :

```
m = a / (n - 1); // среднее арифметическое столбца
```

Comment: Забыли проверку на NULL.

Comment: И кстати, почитайте мои комментарии к оригинальному постингу, может есть что добавить?

Comment: Насчёт переполнения чисел, не будет этого. Так как все числа `<100`. А насчёт того, что не хватит памяти, то это уже *другая* история. Так как я отвечал только насчёт неправильного заполнения массива. @0andriy

Comment: Сегодня не будет, а завтра всё может измениться ;) что касается проверки — это правило хорошего кода. Поскольку вы отвечаете на вопрос новичку, необходимы более общие ответы и лучшие объяснения. Потом же будет сюрприз для них, что оказывается `malloc()` может вернуть NULL.